# how to put if conditional in specify object in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

let say i have object

```
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({
    productName: '',
    quantity: '',
  });
```

how to make if conditional with specify objectname inside? my expextation is

```
if(product.productName != null && product.quantity!= null){
alert('its empty')
}else{
setProduct(bla bla bla)}
```

with this code if i put data in quantity but the other one (productname) is empty the code is always run else (if conditional) is there any advise to strict it? thank you please advise

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are asking here. What is the issue, if any? What are you expecting the code to do versus what it's currently doing?

Comment: You are only checking for null. The empty string is not null.

Comment: Hello Drew Resse, my goal is to set blocking by using if conditional method with that 2 object which is ProductName & Quantity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go this way

```
if(!product.productName && !product.quantity){
alert('its not empty')
}else{
setProduct(bla bla bla)}
```

Comment: nah, still same i try to put one of value let say i just put into quantity then its  still goes into setProduct. but thanks i appreciate it

Comment: please try it:                                                                                
`if(product.productName && product.quantity){
setProduct(bla bla bla)
}else{alert("it is empety")}`

Comment: ok now its work like magic. thank you so much Vida Hedayati.

Answer (score 0):

Try This for checking if product is empty

```
  if (product.productName === "" && product.quantity === "") {
    alert("its empty");
  }else{
    setProduct({ ...product, productName:value });
  }
```

and you can Set product like this in form

```
    setProduct({ ...product, productName:value});
```

Comment: nah, still same i try to put one of value let say i just put into quantity then its still goes into setProduct. but thanks i appreciate it